# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.deleteFromCassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, nosuchmethoderror

Using following versions:

- spark 1.6.2
- scala 2.10.5
- connectorVersion 1.6.8
- cassandra_version 3.0.11.1485

In code, I am using:

```
RDD.deleteFromCassandra("Keyspace","billing_table")
```

and getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
   com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.deleteFromCassandra$default$3()Lcom/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnSelector;
   at purge.PurgeData$.PurgeSubscriptionsFromClosedAcc(PurgeData.scala:112)
   at purge.PurgeData$.PurgeClosedAccountsFromTables(PurgeData.scala:53)
   at purge.Driver$.main(Driver.scala:29)
   at purge.Driver.main(Driver.scala)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:48)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
```

Please, can someone help on this?

Thanks, Chandra

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you deployed your code with spark-submit.
Remember that you should add jar dependency while invoking spark-submit
like this

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.your.package.Class \
  --master local[*] \
  /path/to/your.jar \
  --jars spark-cassandra-connector.jar
```

or use [sbt assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) that  will create jar with all required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

DeleteFromCassandra was only introduced with the SCC Version 2.0.0-RC1 see

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/commit/6944110c9a2790d28c27bf575b8c065684020f1a

Also it is incorrect to use "--jars" to add the spark-cassandra-connector to your spark-submit command as this will not include the dependencies. Instead use the --packages command as specified in the [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md#prerequisites)